# Sitecore: How to get the user profile item of currently logged in user

Tags: c#, sitecore, sitecore7.2

In sitecore:

If a user is logged in with user name "`Addemo`", How Can I get the User profile item which is under `/sitecore/content/Intranet/User Profiles/A/Ad/addemo`.

I tried with  `User.Current.Profile.ProfileItemId;` But the ID I get with this is not the item Id of `addemo` (**/User Profiles/A/Ad/addemo**).

Comment: What product are you using for your Intranet?   The profile path you are expecting, is not one of Sitecores security profile locations.

Comment: I am using `Sitecore Intranet`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It looks like you are using Sitecore Intranet. I'm not 100% familiar with the details of that (mostly my coworkers that work with that part), but this should be what you are looking for:

```
using Sitecore.Intranet.Profiles;
using Sitecore.Intranet.Profiles.Providers;
using Sitecore.Security.Accounts; 

// ------------------------------

var userName = User.Current.Name;
var account = Account.FromName(userName, AccountType.User);

var profileProvider = new UserProfileProvider(new Settings());
var profile = profileProvider.GetProfile(account.LocalName.ToLower());

var profileItem = profile.ProfileItem;
```

I haven't tested this as I don't have a solution at hand, so let me know if something is a bit off.

Comment: Yes I have tested your code and its working. Thanks!!

Answer (score -1):

Sitecore.Context.User has a Profile property, so right you are. You may retrieve custom profile values through **GetCustomProperty()** method, like that:

```
string resetValue = Sitecore.Context.User.Profile.GetCustomProperty("Has Password Reset");
```

or set custom values:

```
Sitecore.Context.User.Profile.SetCustomProperty("Has Password Reset", "1");
```

The profile itself should be somewhere under **/sitecore/templates/System/Security** node. If you want to edit custom profile values for a particular user from UI, you can do that from Sitecore: **User Manager** --> (click a user) --> **Profile** tab --> **Additional Properties** (below)

More to read about:

http://blog.horizontalintegration.com/2014/04/07/sitecore-custom-user-profile-properties/

https://www.markstiles.net/Blog/2013/09/05/Sitecore-Custom-User-Properties.aspx

https://briancaos.wordpress.com/2014/06/12/sitecore-users-custom-profile-properties/